# Mount volumes docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, mount-point

I use the following command to create my own docker container from one of my images

```
docker run -d --name orchestrator --restart unless-stopped -p 80:80 -p 1099:1099 -p 8101:8101 -p 44444:44444 -p 8181:8181 -p 5005:5005 -p 8443:8443 -p 1883:1883 -p 8161:8161 -p 5672:5672 -p 42699:42699 -p 61613:61613 -p 61614:61614 -p 61616:61616 
--mount source=etc,target=/opt/karaf/etc,volume-driver=local,volume-opt=type=none,volume-opt=o=bind,volume-opt=device=’SHARE_DIR/etc/'
--mount source=deploy,target=/opt/karaf/deploy,volume-driver=local,volume-opt=type=none,volume-opt=o=bind,volume-opt=device=’SHARE_DIR/deploy/'
--mount source=log,target=/opt/karaf/data/log,volume-driver=local,volume-opt=type=none,volume-opt=o=bind,volume-opt=device=’SHARE_DIR/log/'
--mount source=configuration,target=/opt/karaf/configuration,volume-driver=local,volume-opt=type=none,volume-opt=o=bind,volume-opt=device='SHARE_DIR/configuration/'
image-name
```

I need to do the same thing with a docker compose, but I have problems especially with the creation of volumes.

Here is my docker-compose.yml

version: "3.2"

```
services: orchestrator:
    build: .
    container_name: orchestrator
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "1099:1099"
      - "8101:8101"
      - "44444:44444"
      - "8181:8181"
      - "5005:5005"
      - "8443:8443"
    volumes:
      - source=configuration target=/opt/karaf/configuration
    volume-driver=local
    volume-opt=type=none
    volume-opt=o=bind
    volume-opt=device='local-path/orch-orch-49-compose/configuration/'
```

Comment: What have you tryied so far, and what is the problem with the volumes?

Comment: My docker compose is: `version: "3.2"
services:
  orchestrator:
    build: .
    container_name: orchestrator
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "1099:1099"
      - "8101:8101"
      - "44444:44444"
      - "8181:8181"
      - "5005:5005"
      - "8443:8443"
    volumes:
      - source=configuration
        target=/opt/karaf/configuration 
        volume-driver=local 
        volume-opt=type=none 
        volume-opt=o=bind
        volume-opt=device='local-path/orch-orch-49-compose/configuration/'`

Comment: The volume syntax looks very odd to me, have you checked the documentation ? https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes

Comment: yes I have tried but without success

Comment: Take a look at the "long syntax" in the documentation, your docker-compose file is nowhere close to the documentation.

Comment: yes, I tried to see the long syntax, but I did not understand how to use it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184083/discussion-between-maurizio-rizzo-and-anthony-raymond).

Comment: @MaurizioRizzo, do you find how parse docker volume params to docker-compose 'long syntax'?

Comment: @AnthonyRaymond, do you find how parse docker volume params to docker-compose 'long syntax'?

Answer (score 0):

The long syntax documentation is [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#long-syntax-3). The volumes section should be something like:

```
volumes:
  - type: volume
    source: my-vol
    target: /opt/karaf/configuration

volumes:
  my-vol:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: 'local-path/orch-orch-49-compose/configuration/'
```

See [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#driver_opts) regarding `driver_opts`.